# What is an efficient way to map unique values of a vector to sequential integers?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R with a vector of non-sequential numbers (`data$SiteID`) that i would like to map to a vector of sequential numbers (`data$site`) to the unique values of `data$SiteID`. Within each site, I would like to map `data$TrtID` to `0` where `data$TrtID == 'control'` or to the next sequential integer, for the other unique `data$TrtID`'s:

```
data <- data.frame(SiteID = c(1,1,1,9,'108','108','15', '15'), 
                   TrtID = c('N', 'control', 'N', 'control', 'P', 'control', 'N', 'P'))
```

1. `data$site` should be `c(1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4)`.
2. `data$trt` should be `c(1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conversion of factors to integers:

```
transform(data, site=as.integer(SiteID), trt=as.integer(TrtID))
```

If the ordering is important, you can give specific orders to the levels:

```
transform(data,
  site = as.integer(factor(SiteID, unique(SiteID))),
  trt  = as.integer(factor(TrtID, unique(c('control', as.character(TrtID))))) - 1L)
```

---

Modified version grouping trt factor by site:

```
transform(data,
  site = as.integer(factor(site_id, unique(site_id))),
  trt  = unsplit(tapply(trt_id, site_id, function(x)
         as.integer(factor(x))), site_id) - 1L)
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to transform() and unsplit(), but why use '1L' instead of 1?

Comment: No probs. Thats only important if you want to keep it as an integer, otherwise you can just drop the L (and you may as well use as.numeric instead of as.integer).

Answer (score 6):

Just treat them as factors:

```
as.numeric(factor(data$SiteID, levels = unique(data$SiteID)))
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 4 4
```

and for the Trt, since you want a 0-based value, subtract one.

```
as.numeric(factor(data$TrtID, levels = sort(unique(data$TrtID))))-1
[1] 1 0 1 0 2 0 1 2
```

Notice that the levels arguments are different - Trt sorts first, which is convinient since control is alphabetically before N or P. If you want a non-standard sorting, you can just explicitly specify the levels in the order you want them.

Comment: thanks that is simple and helpful, but I am not sure what the 'levels' argument does or how to find out this information on my own since ?as.numeric and ?setMethod do not have this info.

Comment: Also, I just changed the question (sorry) because I realized that what I really need is to restart the ordering of the treatments within each site.