# How to create categorical variables from text values in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a data set with a categorical variable `Weather`. This variable has 3 different text values i.e. "Dry", "Drizzle" and "Rain".

I want to create another variable to which I can assign numeric values for these variables. For example `Dry` will be `1`, `Drizzle` will be `2` and `Rain` will be `3`.

As a side information, the `weather` variable will be used to predict blockage in water systems, so I will use this in some sort of linear regression model.

Comment: You can also check a similar post (though not identical) [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620926/using-dplyr-to-get-cumulative-count-by-group)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755473/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-map-unique-values-of-a-vector-to-sequential-integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can convert to `factor` and then coerce to `integer`

```
as.integer(factor(df1$Weather, levels = c("Dry", "Drizzle", "Rain"))
```

Comment: @akrun, wondering why `match(df1$Weather, c("Dry", "Drizzle", "Rain"))` would not be preferable?

Comment: @VincentBonhomme  It can also be used,

Comment: @VincentBonhomme  I haven't checked the benchmarks, `match` could be faster.

Comment: was wondering if there was a "philosophical" reason. did the benchmarks and match is twice faster fyi but around 0.01 sec for 1e6 elements anyway ;-)

Comment: @VincentBonhomme  No other reason except that it comes to my mind first.  So, just gave the instructions to my hand to type that fast and post it :-)

Comment: great. I post it as an answer, just for the record.

Answer (score 3):

For the record, this would also do the job:

```
match(df1$Weather, c("Dry", "Drizzle", "Rain"))
```

This is slightly faster than @akrun's solution (already really fast anyway):

```
x <- sample(c("Dry", "Drizzle", "Rain"), 1e6, rep=T)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
   as.integer(factor(x, levels = c("Dry", "Drizzle", "Rain"))),
   match(x, c("Dry", "Drizzle", "Rain"))
)

Unit: milliseconds
expr      min       lq       mean     median       
14.31158  18.13069  23.19702 20.98414 23.10840 
13.30326  16.00538  19.07544 17.59751 19.53679
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to an ordered factor and assign labels to it:

`data <- data.frame(Weather = c("Drizzle", "Rain", "Drizzle", "Rain", "Dry"))
factor(data$Weather, levels = c("Dry", "Drizzle", "Rain"), labels = c(1, 2, 3), ordered=TRUE)`

Which will return:

`[1] 2 3 2 3 1
Levels: 1 < 2 < 3`

You might also want to read up about using ordered factors in linear regression models.
This question might be a good start:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33413/continuous-dependent-variable-with-ordinal-independent-variable